# Removing final comma from json data

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an issue which has been causing me a headache for a few days and is probably a really simple fix for somebody with a bit more knowledge around json data than me. So hopefully somebody can help.

Firstly, I am using scriptcase, although this shouldn't matter as I am using a blank application and the only scriptcase macro I am utilising in my code is a database lookup, as you will see.

I am essentially selecting multiple fields from the database, preparing them using json to be placed inside a function for a Google Maps API (latitude and longitude, firstname and surname for description). It works perfectly, however throughout the generated array, it automatically places a comma at the end of every line. I cannot get my head around how to remove this. I have tried *rtrim* and *trim*, and neither work, but they do take the value right off of the end of the whole result, if that makes sense?

Apologies in advance if this is incredibly simple!

My code looks like this:

```
$LatLong = array();
$i = 0;
$llresult = '';

sc_lookup(ds,"SELECT latitude,longitude,first_name,surname FROM staff WHERE active=1");

for($i=0;$i<count({ds});$i++){
    $LatLong[0][] = "var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: {lat: ". {ds[$i][0]} .", lng: ". {ds[$i][1]} ."}, map: map, title: '". {ds[$i][2]} ." ". {ds[$i][3]} ."' });";
}



//include $result data
$llresult = json_encode($LatLong);


//$result treatment
$llresult = str_replace("[[","", $llresult);
$llresult = str_replace("]]","", $llresult);
$llresult = str_replace('"','', $llresult);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Locations</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 90%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

    function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: 37.3320045, lng: -122.0329699};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 12,
            center: myLatLng
        });

        <?php echo $llresult; ?>

    }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

<?php
```

I should have added that my output upon echoing the $llresult is showing as the following:

> var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: {lat: 37.3320045, lng:
>   -122.0329699}, map: map, title: 'Joe Bloggs' });,var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: {lat: 37.3320045, lng: -122.0329699},
>   map: map, title: 'Jane Doe' });

Comment: Your approach is incorrect. Javascript codes __must be__ in Javascript.

Comment: you may want to consider adding your markers using the [geojson function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#sample_geojson)

Comment: And in the end you will overwrite your `var Marker` as many times as there are items in array.

Comment: @u_mulder is correect unless you were to append you iterator to the var name you will continue to overwrite it `$LatLong[0][] = "var Marker$i = new google.maps..."`

Comment: Why do you need to `json_encode`? It seems that you are only writting javascript code.

Comment: It's also unclear what is `ds`.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate all comments, I am actually learning with Google Maps/Javascript at this stage... I have followed a tutorial on scriptcase, which didn't actually work... and then adjusted it to work. And as I say the only issue I could see wast the comma in the output. If there is a better method, I am up for that! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qoEDNKAxa_Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach that divides code and data is:

```
$LatLong = array();
$i = 0;

sc_lookup(ds,"SELECT latitude,longitude,first_name,surname FROM staff WHERE active=1");

for($i=0;$i<count({ds});$i++){
    $LatLong[] = [
       'lat' => $ds[$i][0],
       'lng' => $ds[$i][1],
       'title' => $ds[$i][2] . " ". $ds[$i][3]
    ];
}
```

So, now in `$LatLong` you will store coordinates and titles. Now, to javascript:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: myLatLng
});

var latLong = <?php echo json_encode($LatLong)?>;
// iterate over latLong and create markers:
for (var key in latLong) {
    new google.maps.Marker({ 
        position: {lat: latLong[key]['lat'], lng: latLong[key]['lng']}, 
        map: map, 
        title: latLong[key]['title']
    });
}
```

Comment: I really like how clean this is and it outputs nicely, but it won't output past the json_encode. After that, it doesn't do anything. Not sure if I am doing something wrong. The output is showing as this:

Comment: `var latLong = [{"lat":"37.3320045","lng":"-122.0329699","title":"Joe Bloggs"},{"lat":"37.3320045","lng":"-122.0329699","title":"Jane Doe"},{"lat":"37.3320045","lng":"-122.0329699","title":"John Doe"}];

  

  

   for (var key in latLong) {

      new google.maps.Marker({ 

          position: {lat: latLong$this->sc_temp_key['lat'], lng: latLong$this->sc_temp_key['lng']}, 

          map: map, 

          title: latLong$this->sc_temp_key['title']

     });`

Comment: What is `$this->sc_temp_key`?

Comment: That is a good question actually! I think it must be generated by scriptcase once it runs, and not sure if it is a macro or not. I will see if their support is any help on that